# How to catch SecurityException for location permissions

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I'm getting the following crash on certain devices API 6.0+:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to perform any location operations.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcda.zzdw(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdd.zzvQ(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdj.zzvQ(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.location.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbaq.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdd.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdd.zzqq(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdd.onConnected(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.onConnected(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzj(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzrj(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzrk(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Note that **I am asking the user for location permission before making any location related operation**. But for some reason I can't reproduce, some devices seem to be reporting having location permission when I use:

```
boolean hasPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

Because of that, I need to be able to catch the `SecurityException` and ignore it when it happens. Or perhaps figure out a way to tell the user to enable location permissions manually.

The crash above started to happen when I started to use the new APIs from the Play Services to request location using the `FusedLocationProviderClient`. It crashes when I try to do the following without location permissions grated, for example:

`LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).getLocationAvailability().addOnFailureListener(myListener);`

The failure listener does not send the crash to `myListener` unfortunately. Surrounding the above with `try..catch` doesn't work either. I.e., **this doesn't work** and the app crashes anyway throwing `SecurityException`:

```
try {
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        .getLocationAvailability()
        .addOnFailureListener(myListener);
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e(e);
}
```

This problem seems to be related to the following issues:

- [SecurityException in Android Play Services GoogleApiAvailability class](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/xox8L1H-4oQ)
- [Bug: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829071) This one is marked as fixed but the problem seems to be still be present.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to catch in the try/catch?

Comment: please check your menifest some time its happen to forgot give permission in menifest .

Comment: I have the permission in the manifest. The app works for me on all the devices I try. I'm seeing the above issue only on crashlytics.

Comment: @DanielJunyszek I edited the question with an example of what I'm trying to catch.

Comment: Try catching throwable instead of exception

Comment: `SecurityException` is an `Exception` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityException.html) so that won't help unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried on Android 8.0 devices? I just noticed the same crash in one of my apps on crashlytics and it seems limited to Android 8.0 devices.

Comment: It crashes on a subset of Android 6+ devices. I haven't tried recently because for now I reverted back to using the old APIs for getting location.

Comment: I have the exact same issue on some devices since using FusedLocationProviderClient. Do you know if the problem is fixed in some newer Play Services version?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered the fact, that some users revoke the permission after your app was launched? You should always check the permissions every time before calling any methods in `FusedLocationProviderClient`.

Comment: Yes, I check if the permission is present every time on `onResume()` of the activity. I highlighted this in my question: "I am asking the user for location permission before making any location related operation"